# how to save JSON data into SDCard phoneGap

Tags: json, cordova, jquery-mobile, save

We have `sqLite` Table.Now We converted db data into JSON Object.We need JSON data save to my mobile  Sd_Card.Any file like .txt or excel or word any type of format not problem.

We need `JSON` data Save to Local phone-memory or SD-Card.guide me how to save.First Tell me it's possible or not

Answer (score 0):

Well, all you are asking is if it is possible, so that's easy, yes. You said "phone memory" or SD-Card. I assume you mean *persistent* memory, like with WebSQL. Since JSON is just a string, you can insert it into a WebSQL table just fine. You could also, more easier, store it in LocalStorage. Finally, if you want to use the file system, that's simple too, just be sure to add the File plugin.

Comment: in this case we don't have net.So We need JSON data to save to SD_Card.thanks for Reply.i will try File system using FilePlugin

Comment: You don't need Internet access to use WebSQL or LocalStorage either. Just FYI.